# Get data from list containg objects

Tags: python, arrays, json, tensorflow, keras

I have a json format list.There are more than 3000 records in json. I am trying to train my model using keras and tensorflowjs in python but i need to iterate through this list data and take objects data one by one. I need to know that how i can iterate through this data using python so that my model will start reading the values. I just need to iterate through the numpy array in specific variables. so that the data within each variable could be unique with every iteration. I am not well experiences with python so please if you can edit my code then that would be of great help

```
[
  {
    "": 0,
    "attitude.roll": 1.528132,
    "attitude.pitch": -0.733896,
    "attitude.yaw": 0.696372,
    "gravity.x": 0.741895,
    "gravity.y": 0.669768,
    "gravity.z": -0.031672000000000006,
    "rotationRate.x": 0.316738,
    "rotationRate.y": 0.77818,
    "rotationRate.z": 1.0827639999999998,
    "userAcceleration.x": 0.294894,
    "userAcceleration.y": -0.18449300000000002,
    "userAcceleration.z": 0.377542
  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "attitude.roll": 1.527992,
    "attitude.pitch": -0.716987,
    "attitude.yaw": 0.677762,
    "gravity.x": 0.753099,
    "gravity.y": 0.657116,
    "gravity.z": -0.032255,
    "rotationRate.x": 0.842032,
    "rotationRate.y": 0.424446,
    "rotationRate.z": 0.643574,
    "userAcceleration.x": 0.21940500000000002,
    "userAcceleration.y": 0.035845999999999996,
    "userAcceleration.z": 0.11486600000000001
  }
]
```

Here is my Python code

```
import json
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
with open("C:\\Users\\TechProBox\\Desktop\\Model.json") as f:
data = json.load(f)
x1 = np.array(data['attiude.roll'])
y1 = np.array(data['attitude.pitch'])
z1 = np.array(data['attitude.yaw'])
x2 = np.array(data['gravity.x'])
y2 = np.array(data['gravity.y'])
z2 = np.array(data['gravity.z'])
x3 = np.array(data['rotationRate.x'])
y3 = np.array(data['rotationRate.y'])
z3 = np.array(data['rotationRate.z'])
x4 = np.array(data['userAcceleration.x'])
y4 = np.array(data['userAcceleration.y'])
z4 = np.array(data['userAcceleration.z'])

x1_train = x1[:-10000]
y1_train = y1[:-10000]
z1_train = z1[:-10000]
x2_train = x2[:-10000]
y2_train = y2[:-10000]
z2_train = z2[:-10000]
x3_train = x3[:-10000]
y3_train = y3[:-10000]
z3_train = z3[:-10000]
x4_train = x4[:-10000]
y4_train = y4[:-10000]
z4_train = z4[:-10000]
x1_test = x1[:-10000]
y1_test = y1[:-10000]
z1_test = z1[:-10000]
x2_test = x2[:-10000]
y2_test = y2[:-10000]
z2_test = z2[:-10000]
x3_test = x3[:-10000]
y3_test = y3[:-10000]
z3_test = z3[:-10000]
x4_test = x4[:-10000]
y4_test = y4[:-10000]
z4_test = z4[:-10000]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=6))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x1_train, y1_train, z1_train, x2_train, y2_train, z2_train,x3_train, y3_train, z3_train,
            x4_train, y4_train, z4_train,
            epochs=14,
            batch_size=128)

score = model.evaluate(x1_test, y2_test, z3_test, x2_test, y2_test, z2_test, x3_test, y3_test, z3_test,
                        x4_test, y4_test, z4_test, batch_size=128)

print(score)
model.save("Keras-64*2-10epoch")
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model,"tfjsv3")
```

Comment: What do you mean by training using tensorflowJs in Python? Do you mean saving the model topology and its weights using keras and load it after in the Js code?

Comment: @edkeveked yes you are absolutely right and here is the link from where i took help [https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-keras-model-tensorflowjs-tutorial/]

Comment: If I do understand correctly, your goal is to fit your model in Python with your dataset, save the model in a json file and load it back in Js. Currently, you're wrong in the way you're passing the parameters to your fit method.

Comment: @edkeveked yes you are right i want to load my trained model in back in JS but the python code here will train it first. I do know that i am passing wrong parameters to the method but how can i iterate through the json dataset and pass right parameters?

Comment: @edkeveked any suggestions? I was able to put the data in specific arrays in a loop and then i iterated it. But now i am facing typeerror: 'float' object is not subscriptable on line `x1_train = x1[:-10000]`